# Android expected begin_object but was string at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: android, json, gson

when parsing json to those model that i create i got this error but
i check my model with json result in postman still i get this as exception :

JSON result is :

```
{
    "data": {
        "VideoId": [
            {
            
                "Title": "os"
               
            }
           ],
        "Mobile": "+14658908620",
    }
}
```

Model is :

```
public class Response {
 @SeriaizedName("data")
 private Data data ; }
```

and i created getter and setter for it
and another model is :

```
 public class Data{

@SerializedName("VideoId")
private List<VideoList> videoList;

@SerializedName("Mobile")
private String Mobile;}
```

and last model :)

```
public class VideoList {

@SerializedName("Title")
private String Title;}
```

i did't typed getter and setter to prevent be long
so for this model and json i got json parsing exception :

> expected begin_object but was string at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: remove coma `,` at the last Mobile from the server-side response.